# I want to sync my WP8 device (contacts, calender, etc) with my windows server 2008 R2

Tags: sync

I am using windows phone (WP 8), and do have windows 2008 R2 server as my using machine. Whenever I try to install WindowsPhone.exe, it says 'only supported on windows 7 or windows 8'. Earlier I was using WP 7.5 for that I installed Zune package on my windows server 2008 R2 by finding a way to extract the exe and install (it bypasses OS version check).

Now, I want to sync my windows phone 8 device (contacts, calender, etc) with my windows server 2008 R2. For this I want to install WindowsPhone.exe application on windows server 2008.

As there is a way to install zune on windows server 2008 even it is not supported.

My question is - is there any way to install this WindowsPhone.exe desktop application on windows server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 3):

[The Windows Phone app for desktop](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-ie/how-to/wp8/windows-phone-app-for-desktop) is not supported on Windows Server, nor does it sync contact or calendar - only music, pictures and video.

The Zune software only support Windows Phone 7 devices, not Windows Phone 8 (WP8).

## Photos, Music & Video

When a WP8 device is connected to a PC, it's possible to view the phones's media using Windows Explorer

## Contacts & Calendar

Sync your email, contacts, calendar, etc with a service such as Gmail or Outlook.com - then sync that account with your PC.